# How determine if files/folders have a ascending order numbering pattern?

Tags: text-processing

I am trying to determine if all the files/folders present in a directory have a ascending order numbering pattern at same place throughout in their name

If the numbers were always present at a constant place in every case , this would have been super easy

ls $HOME/dir

```
1. Some String
2. Some String- Part 4
3. Some String- Part 5
```

Here i would just simply use something like
`ls $HOME/dir | sort -V | grep -Eo '^[0-9]'`

The command will output 1 2 3 and The files/folders have ascending order numbering pattern is a easy conclusion

Now there are 2 problems here :

1. Its not necessary that these numbers would always be at start like above
2. There could be sometimes random numbers in between

==========================================

ls $HOME/dir

```
Lecture 1 - Some String
Lecture 2 - Some String - Part 4
Lecture 3 - Some String - Part 5
```

Expected Output - 1 2 3

I main thing is that i need grep to only output numbers if they are present in ascending order **at the very same position in filenames** throughout

==========================================

ls $HOME/dir

```
1. Some String
Some String - Part 2
Some String - Part 3
```

For something like this , grep shouldn't output anything at all because even though it has ascending numbers in name, they are not present at same place throughout

==========================================

PS / The 'Some String' part in all my example would be different for each file/folders. Only the position of the ascending numbers being constant (If any ) is  to be considered

One More  final example

ls $HOME/dir

```
CB) Lecture 1 xyz
CB) Lecture 2 abc-part 8
CB) Lecture 3 pqr-part 9
```

Expected Output - 1 2 3

Comment: could you have something like `abc 3 xyz 1 foo` and `ijk 8 xyz 2 baz` and you still want `1` and `2` as output? Or do you always want to check only the first matched number in the string?

Comment: @Sundeep yes i would still want 1 and 2 as output in that example as they are 1) ascending 2) occur at the very same position. If doesn't matter if that ascending number is first matched number or not . A ascending pattern could only be indentified by atleast comparing 2 or more files/folders

Comment: Going by your example , even if it was modified to be ```abc 1 xyz 3 foo``` and ```ijk 2 xyz 8 baz```.  1 and 2 should still be printed as output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution using AWK:

printnumbers.awk

```
BEGIN {
    numberRegex = "[0-9]+([^A-Za-z0-9]|$)"
}

NR == 1 {
    numberPos = match($0, numberRegex)
}

match($0, numberRegex) == numberPos {
    matchedString = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
    match(matchedString, "[0-9]+")
    result = result substr(matchedString, RSTART, RLENGTH) "\n"
    next
}

{
    result = ""
    exit 1
}

END {
    printf("%s", result)
}
```

Then run

```
$ ls $HOME/dir | sort -V | awk -f printnumbers.awk
```

**Edit 2021-05-14**

A second approach is to split each line into fields with non-digits as separators. Then each field is either a number or an empty string. For each line we check the fields to see if a sequence of consecutive numbers starting from one is formed.

Here is the logic:

```
BEGIN {
    FS = "[^0-9]+"
}

{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        numbersConsecutive[i] = ($i == NR) && ((NR == 1) || numbersConsecutive[i])
    }
    if (NF > numbersConsecutiveLen) {
        numbersConsecutiveLen = NF
    }
}

END {
    consecutiveNumbersFound = 0
    for (i = 1; i <= numbersConsecutiveLen; i++) {
        if (numbersConsecutive[i]) {
            consecutiveNumbersFound = 1
        }
    }
    if (consecutiveNumbersFound) {
        for (i = 1; i <= NR; i++) {
            print i
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate your answer , i tested it for a bit . Looks really good just found one issue explained here - https://del.dog/raw/vidomolyst. i had mentioned in question that numbering would always start from 1 , my bad it somehow got edited out , question being very long . Your awk function is printing 720 for all three lines .. expected Output is 1 2 3.   Would be grateful if you could do this small change

Comment: @Sachin OK, I updated the AWK script to reflect this.

Comment: I think there's a small typo in script somewhere because its still printing 720 for each lines when i tested it

Comment: I am sorry , it got delayed to report back if everything is okey
I found one issue - https://del.dog/raw/prerubesin . Currently script just takes the first number and prints it irrespective of whether its in ascending order.  As you can see in above example it prints 8 8 8 , when it should actually print 1 2 3

Comment: Also technically it shouldn't even consider a number if it starts from 8 , it would be always start from 1 as earlier mentioned .. 

You could use this logic. 
1)  If number 1 is detected in first line , check if its increasing  in ascending order throughout all files in same position 

2) 
If yes , then print these numbers
If no , then check if first line had another number 1 at different place
If yes , then check if its increasing  in ascending order throughout all files at same position  , if yes print them

If no , then exit script

Comment: @Sachin I have added a solution which should work.